# Can't interact with input elements

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have scraped and automated this website before, but never the login page.
This is the [website](https://onwin.com.br/login).
I normally use this type of logic to interact with the elements in this page:

```
# CLS_BTN could be ".div class="col-12 form-title text-center py-4""
# Always use '.' as a prefix
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, CLS_BTN)))
ele_inputs = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, CLS_BTN)
```

These are my problems:

1. When you load the website for the first time there is a notification/popup page in the the middle of the screen and this will break my code, this notification/popup will go away only if a click in it, click outiside of it or press enter.
2. Can't interact with the inputs and the button of the page
   this is where the inputs and the button are: `<form class="row" method="post">`

And this is what's inside (where the inputs and button are):

```html
<div class="col-12 form-title text-center py-4"><div class="t">Bem-vindo.</div> <div class="d">Por favor, faça login na sua conta.</div></div> <div class="col-12 form-group"><input type="text" placeholder="Nome de usuário ou e-mail" required="required" autocomplete="username" aria-required="true" class="inp-pri form-control" id="__BVID__58"></div> <div class="col-12 form-group"><input type="password" placeholder="Senha" required="required" autocomplete="current-password" aria-required="true" class="inp-pri form-control" id="__BVID__59"> <div class="f-s-14 py-3"><a href="/forgot-password" class="text-vio" target="_self">Esqueceu a senha?</a></div></div> <div class="col-12 mb-md"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-pri f-s-18 f-w-b py-3 text-uppercase w-100">ENTRAR</button></div> <div class="col-12 mb-md text-center py-4 f-f-r f-s-16">Ainda não é membro? <a href="/register" class="text-pri font-weight-bold" target="_self">Entrar</a></div>
```

I have tried the following classes:

```
CLS_BTN = ".btn btn-default btn-pri f-s-18 f-w-b py-3 text-uppercase w-100"
CLS_BTN = ".btn btn-default btn-pri f-s-18 f-w-b py-3 text-uppercase w-100"
CLS_BTNS = ".inp-pri form-control"
CLS_PARENT = ".col-12 form-group"
CLS_NEW_BTN = ".col-12 mb-md"

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, CLS_BTN)))
ele_inputs = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, CLS_BTN)
```

and the following ids:

```
ID_USR_EMAIL = "__BVID__988" #__BVID__58
ID_PASS = "__BVID__989"
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, ID_PASS)))
ele_inputs = driver.find_element(By.ID, ID_PASS)
```

As you can see the ID's from user and password can change from day to day, for example today us `"__BVID__58"` and yesterday it was `"__BVID__988"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a general solution to the problem you're facing:

```
#Package imports.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time

def login_to_website():
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
    options.add_argument('incognito')
    service = Service(executable_path=r'chromedriver.exe')

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=service)
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    driver.get('https://onwin.com.br/login')

    try:
        center_ad = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//picture[@class='w-100']")
        center_ad.click()
    except:
        print('We cannot find the ad/picture this time.')

    username_field = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@autocomplete='username']")
    username_field.send_keys('<MY_USERNAME>')

    password_field = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@autocomplete='current-password']")
    password_field.send_keys('<MY_PASSWORD>')

    login_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@type='submit']")
    login_button.click()

    time.sleep(20)

login_to_website()
```

Compared to your approach, I do some things differently:

1. I use an implicit wait of 30 seconds (in `driver.implicitly_wait(30)`) to wait for the popup image in case it comes. You can adjust this implicit wait by playing around with the times to see what balances speed and accuracy in finding elements.
2. I find elements by XPATH rather than by CSS selector or ID. The advantage of this is that it solves the ID problem you're facing, specifically that the IDs of these elements change daily. Instead, by finding elements by XPATH, I search for elements by attributes which do not change; for example, the `<input>` for usernames has a `autocomplete` attribute which is constant and I can search by.
3. The picture/ad that you need to click on does not alway appear, so we can look for it within a try-except block. If we can find the picture (again, by XPATH, not ID), we can click on it. If we can't find it and get an error (such as a NoSuchElementException), we move on to the login phase.

I showed this solution in Incognito mode so we can see the ad/popup image more often and click on it. I am using Google Chrome version 115. The `time.sleep()` calls are merely for demonstration purposes to slow down execution so that we can see it work in real time.